# What is the best strategy to update a persistent domain object graph in bulk?

Tags: java, javascript, hibernate, angularjs, batch-processing

I am working on a Java-based web application with Spring, Hibernate, Angular, etc., and users in this application can edit entities that have large object graphs. In one part of the application, it's actually quite natural to edit these entities all in 1 update using a multi-step or tabbed UI component rather than give them the chance to make separate smaller edits, because I want to give them the ability to bail out and cancel their modifications without having to undo anything on the server.

I am not sure of the best strategy to implement this though. If the updated object contains drastically different children and children of those children, it will be quite difficult to figure out which objects to delete, update and insert based on the 'before' and 'after' object graphs, and which properties require updating for existing objects.

1. One idea I thought of is to record the states of the user's
   interactions, and then send those to the server instead of the
   object graph. So if 3 children existed prior to the edits, and the
   user deletes 2 children and adds 1 new one, I could send an array of
   3 states representing the deletes and inserts in the exact order the
   user did them in, and just replicate that on the server.

   Here's a superficial example that also illustrates a problem with this approach:

   ```
   [{'delete', 'Dog', {id: 5}},
    {'insert', 'Dog', {name: 'Freddy'}},
    {'update', 'Dog', {id: 3, name: 'Bob'}}]
   ```

   The one issue I see with this approach is that it can be rather confusing logic-wise to determine if the user adds `Freddy` and then decides to change it to another name later on because we don't have an id reference - it hasn't been persisted to the server yet.

   We can't generate all of the inserts upon submit, because there may be some dependency issues - the order can be relevant in some cases, while not all. I don't see a good solution to this problem without a ton of framework support to track the states properly. It is frankly beyond what I can do in the timeframe I have.
2. I guess another way to accomplish this is to simply delete the whole thing and insert all of the new stuff, but that seems a bit unpure. Can it really be that simple? I guess database keys will grow at a much faster rate. If any other objects unrelated to this object graph are linked, they will lose their references, which is probably not going to work.
3. I think perhaps the safest and most sure method is to do very detailed object comparisons and find the algorithm that make A into B 100% of the time without losing the existing object references. If this is not done in some open-source project, then it will take some time to write I guess.

Is there any better ways to accomplish this, or should I just abandon the idea and simply force users to make updates one-at-a-time in real-time?

Comment: I wouldn't go for 3 as dealing with collections in Hibernate is a nightmare.

Comment: @Ean Maybe, just to get the stupid project done, I should make all of the edits in real time... and then go back and fix this problem later. I am not sure what the best way to solve it is. It seems like every solution has a drawback.

Comment: In a similar scenario, I did like your second solution. Fortunately I did not have the problem with referencing tables. And yes database keys will grow faster but if you don't delete the previous records, you can keep a track of changes (like a history) as well! Your business people may like it, who knows? ;-)

Comment: I'm at a loss actually. I'm just not going to do it.